# How do I do a 'git status' so it doesn't display untracked files without using .gitignore?

Tags: git, version-control

How do I do a `git status` so it doesn't display untracked files without using `.gitignore`?  I want to get modification status information on tracked files only.

Comment: Each user's preference is going to be different, but you can compare the output of 3 different status calls and it will probably inspire you to script a solution. `vimdiff <(git status --untracked-files=no) <(git status) <(git status --untracked-files)`

Answer (score 586, accepted):

Use this:

```
git status -uno
```

which is equivalent to:

```
git status --untracked-files=no
```

It's a bit hidden in the manuals, but the manpage for status says "supports the same options as git-commit", so that's where you'd have to look.

Comment: Where do you write this? Into terminal or into file?

Comment: That's a command-line  operation; not a git config file edit.

Comment: What if I have done, git reset --hard <commit id> , then I git status -uno, nothing show up, only untracked files shown

Comment: Funnily enough, this is **not the same** as `git status --no-untracked-files` :D

Comment: @Fritz Would you explain what is the difference?

Comment: @IvanDimitrov: I have no idea what `--no-untracked-files` does, and I have not been able to find anything about it online (it doesn't do anything for me). But when you enter `git status --no-` in your Terminal and then press `Tab Tab`, it will suggest  `--no-untracked-files` as an option. This seems to suggest that it should do something, and git does not complain if you give it that option. But as I said, it doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 143):

Also:

```
git config status.showuntrackedfiles no
```

Comment: This is great for a repo that always has untracked files like one in your home directory for dot-files.

Comment: Dave, Perhaps `.gitignore` listing is best for "known unknowns", whereas you may wish to see ["unknown unknowns"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There_are_known_knowns) that pop up anew.

Answer (score 19):

Note that, since [git 1.8.3 (April, 22d 2013)](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.3.txt#L127-L128), you will know about the `--untracked-files=no` even if you didn't add that option in the first place!

> "`git status`" suggests users to look into using `--untracked-files=no` option when it takes too long.

See [commit https://github.com/git/git/commit/5823eb2b28696bf0eb25f6ca35b303447869f85](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5823eb2b28696bf0eb25f6ca35b303447869f85):

> In some repositories users experience that "`git status`" command takes long time.
>   The command spends some time searching the file system for untracked files.
>
> Explain the trade-off struck by the default choice of `normal` to help users make an appropriate choice better, before talking about the configuration variable.

The [`git status` documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-status) now states:

> When `-u` option is not used, untracked files and directories are shown (i.e. the same as specifying `normal`), to help you avoid forgetting to add newly created files.
>   **Because it takes extra work to find untracked files in the filesystem, this mode may take some
>    time in a large working tree.
>
>   You can use `no` to have `git status` return more quickly without showing untracked files**.
>
> The default can be changed using the **`status.showUntrackedFiles`** configuration variable documented in [`git config`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config).

Comment: @Tshepang thank you. I have edited the answer to include the proper link, as well as to add the exact commit in which said change was introduced.

Comment: I am new to git - can you please tell me where to write these commands for not-showing untracked files? I've tried to write them into terminal, but untracked files are still showing.

Comment: @FrenkyB What did you type exactly in your terminal (which OS by the way? And which git version are you using?)

Comment: OS = Windows 10 Pro, Source Tree version = 1.9.10.0, how can I check GIT version? What I've typed into terminal is: git commit -u --untracked-files=no. I still see those files in Source Tree.