# Keep ignored files out of git status

Tags: git, gitignore

I would like to stop Git from showing ignored files in `git status`, because having tons of documentation and config files in the list of *Changed but not updated* files, renders the list half-useless.

Is it normal for Git to show these files?

I put the ignore information in a `.gitignore` file in the root directory of the Git repository and they are not added when using `git add .` but it seems that they are not fully ignored either, as they show up in the aforementioned list and **do not** show up in the list printed by `git ls-files --others -i --exclude-standard`. Only files matched by the patterns in `~/.gitignore` show up there.

Could it be because at an earlier stage I didn't ignore them and they were thus committed at least once?

Answer (score 305, accepted):

As I found [in this post](https://web.archive.org/web/20090926065622/http://www.pagebakers.nl/2009/01/29/git-ignoring-changes-in-tracked-files/), `.gitignore` only works for untracked files. If you added files to repository, you can:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>
```

or remove them from repository by

```
git rm --cached <file>
```

*Edit*

[This article](http://www.gitready.com/beginner/2009/01/19/ignoring-files.html) explains that too

Comment: `git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>` didn’t work (had tried that), but `git rm --cached <file>` did the job. Thanks!

Comment: update-index worked for me. Similiar problem where git status is showing ignored files... very annoying. +1

Comment: I still have this problem. Neither of the above commands worked for me. In both cases git says it has no knowledge of the files in question but they still show up in git status :(

Comment: @Cfreak Does `git status -- <file>` show "Changes not staged for commit" or "Untracked files" for your file? The former is if you already have file in index and I would need more informations to solve your problem (better create separate question with git messages shown and just post link to it in comment). The later is for files which are not tracked by git (yet), but are not in `.gitignore` file and can be freely added to index.

Comment: @MBO - yes it does. Thank you! Your comment helped me find this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/594757/how-do-i-do-a-git-status-so-it-doesnt-display-untracked-files-without-using which worked for me.

Comment: i used `git rm --cached` and now in `git status` i see changes to be commited `deleted: ...` is it okay ?

Comment: First option works like a charm. I already tried the second one, and it caused the files to be staged as "removed" and I definitely didn't want that.

Comment: Most people are searching for the first solution, not the second one.
So careful to not remove the files from your repository (which is the second solution).
The first one will just ignore from the git status and not show them.

Comment: But what if I need to do this on all files in a folder? The folder is called `dist`

Comment: git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>
worked for me.

Comment: How do you list the files that are assumed unchanged? Edit: This works: `git ls-files -v | grep '^[a-z]'`

Answer (score 30):

I've had this issue come up as well, it's probably because you added your ignored directory/files to .gitignore after they were marked as "to be tracked" by GIT in an initial commit flow.

So you need to clear the git tracking cache like so:

`git rm --cached -r [folder/file name]`

A more detailed explanation can be read here:
http://www.frontendjunkie.com/2014/12/stop-git-from-tracking-changes-to.html

The above command also removed the remnants of the folder/files from your remote GIT origin. So your GIT repos become clean.

Answer (score 27):

Problem can be that this file is still in the git cache. To solve this problem needs to reset git cache.

#### For single file

```
git rm --cached <file>
```

#### For whole project

Reset git cache. It is good command if you committed project when .gitignore file was not added.

```
git rm -r --cached .
```

#### Commit changes

```
git add . 
git commit -m ".gitignore was fixed."
```

Answer (score 4):

This surely works,

`git rm --cached -r [folder/file name]`

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want not to add tmp directory (Visual Studio Platform)

1- add lines below to your local .gitignore file

```
## ignore tmp
/tmp/
./tmp/
```

3- backup and delete tmp Folder locally. (Backup somewhere else. eg desktop?)

4- Commit Changes to Local than Sync to Remote (eg. github).

After these steps your tmp directory wont be uploaded again.

Answer (score 0):

From *man git-lsfiles*:

```
-i, --ignored
Show ignored files in the output. Note that this also reverses any exclude list present.
```

Personally I tend to keep doxygen files in my source tree, so I simply added this to my .gitignore (which is in the topmost directory of my source tree):

```
docs/*
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Following steps work for **untracked files** only.
This info is applicable for following configuration:

```
Platform: linux

Git version: git version 1.8.3.1
```

Put list of files to be ignored in "exclude" file present at following location.

```
<path till .git directory>/.git/info/exclude
```

Initial content of "exclude" file

```
# git ls-files --others --exclude-from=.git/info/exclude
# Lines that start with '#' are comments.
# For a project mostly in C, the following would be a good set of
# exclude patterns (uncomment them if you want to use them):
# *.[oa]
# *~
```

Final content of "exclude" file

```
# git ls-files --others --exclude-from=.git/info/exclude
# Lines that start with '#' are comments.
# For a project mostly in C, the following would be a good set of
# exclude patterns (uncomment them if you want to use them):
# *.[oa]
# *~


*.tar
*.gch
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the accepted answer, you can **assume the file as unchanged**, so that whatever you do on your local machine is not commited to your remote branch.

Something like `git update-index --assume-unchanged src/main/resources/config.properties`
where src/main.resources/config.properties is a sample for the path to find that file within your project.

Now, if you want to **remove the file completely** from your repository, you may want to use `remove cached` instead as of `git rm --cached

This scenario could be applicable on the following situation:

> Let's suppose I have a file where I store passwords. I've initially commited that file with wrong details, just so my colleagues have that same file on their machines. However, now I've added my correct details on my local machine. How do I prevent that file from being accidentally committed again with the now correct password details?

Answer (score 0):

after Make changes in .gitignore file.
follow these simple steps

```
git rm -r --cached .

Run git add .

git commit -m "Commit message"
```

To check

```
git status
```

Answer (score -3):

like this

```
git --ignored myfolder
```

And will show status only for **myfolder**