# Get git not to show untracked files

Tags: git

When doing `git commit`, is there a way to not display the untracked files in my editor (defined in `$EDITOR`)? I know how to do so in the shell (`git status -uno`), but I'd like do it in editor as well.

Note that I do not want to ignore these files forever; I just don't want to see them on certain occasions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I do a 'git status' so it doesn't display untracked files without using .gitignore?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/594757/how-do-i-do-a-git-status-so-it-doesnt-display-untracked-files-without-using)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

From the [git-commit](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit.html) man page:

```
       -u[], --untracked-files[=]
           Show untracked files (Default: all).

           The mode parameter is optional, and is used to specify the handling of untracked
           files. The possible options are:

           ·   no - Show no untracked files

           ·   normal - Shows untracked files and directories

           ·   all - Also shows individual files in untracked directories.

               See git-config(1) for configuration variable used to change the default for
               when the option is not specified.
```

Comment: Great thing about git is they're really trying to keep command line options consistent between commands with similar functionality.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to change the setting permanently, but independently for the `status` and `commit` commands? I want to see them with `status`, but not for `commit`, but `git-config(1)` shows only the option `status.showUntrackedFiles` which effects both commands.

Comment: Can I please ask you how to write this command into source tree? I've tried running terminal and write git commit -u --untracked-files=no, but received error.

Comment: Sorry - it wasn't error, but I still see untracked files. I don't understand where should this command be written - into terminal or somewhere else?

Comment: @FrenkyB You need to use either -u no or --untracked-files=no, not both.

Answer (score 107):

If you don't *ever* want to commit them to your repo, use a `.gitignore` file to ignore them. More details can be found on the [`gitignore` man page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html). They won't show up as untracked files when entering your commit message in your `$EDITOR`.

If you simply don't want to see them when committing in any repo, set the Git config variable `status.showUntrackedFiles` to `no`, as noted [here](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html):

```
$ git config --global status.showUntrackedFiles no
```

For applying this to a single repo, instead use:

```
$ git config --local status.showUntrackedFiles no
```

Comment: if you want to ignore the untracked files in the current repo only, rather than globally use:  `git config --local status.showUntrackedFiles no`

Comment: @yaitloutou, Your extension should be added into the answer.

Comment: @yaitloutou, will one have to run that command everytime one formats one's computer and checks out that repo, or is that setting save with the repo (by using `--local`)

Comment: @run_the_race, yes. by default git configs (being local, global, or otherwise) are not persistents. Since each collaborator should have their own. 
Although, you can add a `.gitconfig` file in the repo root, then include its settings, as explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/18330114/2245329. 
In this case, It's easier to just rerun the command once per format though imo

Answer (score 10):

You can temporary use the git commit option `-uno` to mask untracked files (`git help commit`).

If you want a permanent solution use the `.gitignore` file.

For instance, if you want to ignore the file `bar.foo` and any file with the `.bak` extension, you juste have to create a `.gitignore` file in the root directory of your project containing :

```
bar.foo
*.bak
```

Some file are ignored by a global `gitignore` file (for instance, dot file and directory are ignored).

Answer (score 5):

Add the file names - or templates (wild cards) for the file names - to the .gitignore file and add that to the repository:

```
git add .gitignore
git commit -m 'Added .gitignore file'
```

For example, for my Go repository, I have a .gitignore file containing:

```
*.o
*.a
*.so
*.pl
*.6
*.out
_obj/
_cgo_defun.c
_cgo_export.c
_cgo_export.h
_cgo_gotypes.go
*.cgo1.go
*.cgo2.c
example/example
ifix1/esqlc-cmds.c
```

I should probably compress the '`_cgo_`' names with a wild card; the other '.c' file is generated from a '.ec' file so it does not need to be tracked.

Answer (score 5):

There are times notifications aren't wanted about either a changed repo file or a new file that needs to be added to the repo.  However, adding the name of the file to `.gitignore` might not be a good option, either.  For example, locally-generated files that other users aren't likely to generate (e.g., files created by an editor) or files of experimental test code might not be appropriate to appear in a `.gitignore` file.

In those cases, use one of these solutions:

1. **If the file is a changed repo file**

   Use the command:

   `git update-index --assume-unchanged "$FILE"`

   To undo this, use the command:

   `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged "$FILE"`

   The `update-index` command doesn't work with new files that haven't been added to the repo yet, though.
2. **If the file is new and not added to the repo**

   Add its filename to the repo's `exclude` file:

   `echo "$FILE" >> .git/info/exclude`

   This also works for changed repo files, but there isn't a specific undo command for it.  The `exclude` file would need to be edited and the filename deleted from it.  Or other commands could approximate it:

   `ex -s -c"g/^${FILE}\$/d" -cwq .git/info/exclude`

   Note that this overwrites the existing `exclude` file and if the filename specified contains special characters that could affect the regular expression, the results are unpredictable.

   This usage of the `exclude` file is recommended by the page ["Ignoring files" on GitHub Help](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/#explicit-repository-excludes).

Answer (score -1):

If you are using git-extensions tool 
in the commit tab just select the files you want to ignore, right click and add them to .gitignore