# How to store a git config as part of the repository?

Tags: git

I'm using filters to mangle files during checkout like described [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion).
Now the problem is that filter definition is only stored in my local configuration file:

```
$ cat .git/config
....
[filter "dater"]
        smudge = /home/.../expand_date
        clean = perl -pe \"s/\\\\\\$Date[^\\\\\\$]*\\\\\\$/\\\\\\$Date\\\\\\$/\"
```

If my coworkers want to benefit from this `Date` expansion, they need to copy my filter definition. And if I change it, I need to notify them, etc..

So can I store this filter definition part of `.git/config` in repository and make git use it?

Comment: You may find [this link](https://github.com/stefanhoelzl/share-git-hooks-and-config) useful to automatically share a team-wide configuration.

Answer (score 271, accepted):

There are 3 supported scopes of `.gitconfig` file: `--system, --global, --local`. You can also create a custom configuration file, and include it in one of the supported files.

For your needs **custom** - is the right choice. Instead of writing your filter in `.git/config` you should save it in `.gitconfig` file in your repository root:

```
your-repo/
│
├── .git/
│   ├── config
│
├── .gitconfig
│
```

Create the `.gitconfig` with your filter and commit the changes. Then your colleagues will always keep it updated -- but they will have to include it manually. **It is not possible to automatically include your custom configuration file** through git alone, because it creates a security vulnerability.

To apply this configuration for a single repository, each user will need to run the following command in `your-repo/`:

```
git config --local include.path ../.gitconfig
```

Reference: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_includes

Be careful not to store personal data in the custom `.gitconfig`, like `user.*`, keep those in your global `.gitconfig`.

Comment: I want to avoid notifying each possible user that it needs to include repo's `.gitconfig` in his `~/.gitconfig`. No one will remember it. Is there a way to make git to ALWAYS read the repo's `.gitconfig`.

Comment: @ZaarHai: I'm guessing no, because that would be dangerous. (Imagine cloning a repo that aliases commands with something "interesting", eg. exporting the contents of your home dir). If you've got something like a `configure` script or similar that users must run, you could have that set the include (or prompt the user to).

Comment: How do you tell git to use a repo's own .gitconfig file? I have created one but it's not being parsed.

Comment: @HenryBlyth there seems to be a `--file` option on `git config`, you can then set it to point on your repo's `.gitconfig`. I haven't tested it yet, but it seems to answer your question.

You can read it on the docs.

http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#FILES

Comment: the solution works, but it doesn't work after _git pull_ by another team member

Comment: Be great if Git didn't assume you're writing code distributed outside your org where you have to care about security threats.  Sometimes system usability and automation has a higher priority than security.

Comment: You can sneakily add the command to a task (assuming you're using a task runner) routinely used by your team.

Comment: @Mieszko Do you not find slipping your coworkers unexpected code to trick them into executing it ethically questionable?

Comment: @Synoli I was being ironic, as  It's a bad idea from the separation of concerns standpoint. Nevertheless, it would be ethical if not held secret and enforcing a legitimate rule.

Comment: @Mieszko and @Synoli, I often add a Makefile to my projects and when needed I insert a `make setup` command that is needed for the project to run correctly. It is explicit so no ethical concerns and semantic so no problem with separation of concerns. But it has the drawback of having everyone remembering to run it when they clone a project, but if you do this for all your projects that might need it becomes easy to remember.

Comment: It looks like you can edit the pre-commit file under .git/hooks to include the command to include the local .gitconfig file `git config --local include.path ../.gitconfig`

Comment: @gb2d, .git/hooks is also local, not versioned, so that just adds a level of indirection to the same problem.

Comment: You could start an `.envrc` file containing `git config --local include.path .gitconfig` and if the user has direnv installed they would allow the reading of the file and it would be automated.

Answer (score 32):

You can not use `.gitconfig` file in a git repository by default, but you can link to it so the git config will be versioned.

You can link to it like that:

```
[include]
  path = ../.gitconfig
```

I have created a simple **script** `gitconfig.sh` which do it for you (much faster than copy) + simple `.gitconfig` file so if you want, take a look to this repo https://github.com/HoBi/dotfiles.

---

**EDIT**: I have deleted the file, but you can find it here https://github.com/tenhobi/dotfiles/blob/7e4376c006c508370b82bc7bd37173fab51dbd01/git/.gitconfig.sh

Comment: @HoBi it seems that you have now deleted your gitconfig.sh from GitHub, any reason why you no longer wanted it?

Comment: @NoviceC There is the file if ya want it. https://github.com/HoBi/dotfiles/blob/7e4376c006c508370b82bc7bd37173fab51dbd01/git/.gitconfig.sh

I have came to believe, that you shouldn't store .gitconfig or gitconfig.sh in you git project - these are personal settings and should be stored in your global settings in `~/` folder. And everybody might have different need, so why bother everybody with your config in git repo. :-)

Comment: @tenhobi there are some configs that might be interesting for everyone to share in a project. I will do so for aliases, with project coding flow

Comment: But it means I have to load it every time with a "git config --local include.path", right?
The question is about how to make it completely default for a repo, without setting every time.

Answer (score 0):

This question and it's answers still helped me 10.5 years after being asked!

I needed to add different user details for my self at the repository level due to working with one user name and email at work and another privately. To simplify things I create repository templates and then just copy the template to create a new project, but you can use the same principal if you don't like that approach.

My solution:

1. Create a folder called NewRepo and initialise it as a repository.
2. Add .gitconfig in the repository root with private user details.
3. Add this to the local config as explained by others

`git config --local include.path ../.gitconfig`

4. Add .gitignore in the repository root with this:

> ```
> # THE .gitconfig FILE MUST BE IGNORED IT IS ADDED USING:
> # git config --local include.path ../.gitconfig
> # The above command will add it to the '.git/config' file
> # It allows for a user to work on different projects with different user details
> # to those stored globally at the user level e.g. private and work environments.
>
> *.gitconfig
>
> # Other Files
>
> # Folders
> ```

5. Stage the ignore file and commit.
6. Convert to bare master repository for central use as required, from parent folder:

   git clone --bare NewRepo Template.git
7. Use the NewRepo folder if just using it locally, or the Template.git folder if copying to my file server, as a template for my private projects.