# How to commit autocrlf setting in repository

Tags: git, core.autocrlf

We are working cross platform on Windows, Linux and Mac, we collaborate using GIT. Recently we stumbled upon `autocrlf` settings to avoid `Carriage Return` and `Line Feed`, and found out they show case different behavior on different platform.

We found a workaround to mark `autocrlf = false`. But every team mate has to change her setting on his machine.

My question is, **Do we have some workaround by which we could check-in the autocrlf setting in the repo, so that user doesn't have to change her setting on its own?** And the setting is automatically updated.

Comment: One hint: Configure the linefeeds in your appropriate IDE you are using, and not in git.

Comment: Seems like you might want to investigate [gitattributes](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes).  The `.gitattributes` file can specify exactly how to treat your text files.  And best of all, the `.gitattributes` file is checked into the repo like any other source file.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible to do this without forcing every user to update something in his settings.

See, e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18329621/storing-git-config-as-part-of-the-repository)

What you could do is create server-side hooks that refuse commits in which line endings are changed, and informs the developer on how to correctly set up his git environment...