# merge-request with a command line

Tags: command-line, git-bash

In the moment, each time I want to make a merge-request, I commit my changes and push it online with

```
git commit -am 'My changes'
git push origin my_branch:my_branch
```

and then on Gitlab, manually, I make a merge-request and assign the CTO.

How directly from bash could I create a merge-request an assigning the CTO?

I know there exists the following answer [Is it possible to create merge requests in pure Git from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273434/is-it-possible-to-create-merge-requests-in-pure-git-from-the-command-line/7282908#7282908), but that didn't answer my question.

How can I create a merge-request from `my_branch` to master?
Could I do `git --assign=CTO request-pull my_branch master`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a GitLab merge request via command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37410262/how-to-create-a-gitlab-merge-request-via-command-line)

Comment: You can check github.com/vishwanatharondekar/gitlab-cli does what you want including the assignee support.

Answer (score 0):

Use [push options](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/push_options.html). Here is an example.

```
git push -o merge_request.create -o merge_request.assign="CTO"
```