# How to create pull request through terminal?

Tags: git, azure, terminal, gitlab

Can we create pull request through terminal or command prompt? Is there any command which we can run to create pull request and merge for:

- Git
- Gitlab
- Azure

If anyone has an idea, please share it.

Comment: Gitlab has REST APIs to manipulate pull requests (named merge requests in Gitlab), https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#create-mr. You can use `curl` or Python's `requests` to call the API. You can also install `python-gitlab`, which is more user friendly, https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/.

Answer (score 1):

2020: Git itself would not create a pull request to GitLab.

Beside the [API call](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#create-mr) mentioned by [ElpieKay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6330106/elpiekay), you also have the more convenient [CLI glab](https://github.com/profclems/glab), and its commands:

- [`glab mr create`](https://github.com/profclems/glab/blob/4866d691dad97e0c3d12812b3653faaea7624ed3/docs/source/mr/create.rst) command.
- [`glab mr merge`](https://github.com/profclems/glab/blob/4866d691dad97e0c3d12812b3653faaea7624ed3/docs/source/mr/merge.rst)

Its [latest release](https://github.com/profclems/glab/releases/latest) includes that client already pre-compiled for various platform, so you should be able to drop it in your Azure environment.

---

Update Dec. 2022: the project is now [`gitlab-org/cli`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cli), and the documentation: [`glab mr create`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cli/-/blob/main/docs/source/mr/create.md).
See "[How to create a GitLab merge request via command line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74896036/6309)" for the official integration.