# How can I track text files with proper line endings normalization using git-lfs?

Tags: git, gitattributes, git-lfs

I have a repository to which I would like to add large text data files. Due to their number and size (which can be up to approximately 100MB in some cases), I would like to track those files with `git-lfs`.

I've added such a file with `git lfs track data.txt`, and changed the default `-text` (which specifies a binary file) to `text=auto` in the `.gitattributes` file (as documented in [git-scm's gitattributes documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes)). This gives me a `.gitattributes` which looks like:

```
data.txt filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs text=auto
```

And just to be sure, I have [refreshed the repository](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/#refreshing-a-repository-after-changing-line-endings). Even so, it seems that the file is still tracked as a binary object and correspondingly the end-of-line conversion filter is not applied on check-out (i.e. the file is getting checked-out with the original line endings it was checked-in with).

I've also tried with `text=crlf` (and the variant `text eol=crlf`) with the same result. I have seen a number of documents and tutorials about using `git-lfs` but they all seem to be geared towards tracking binary files (such as [`*.bin`](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/wiki/Tutorial), [images](https://github.com/blog/2079-managing-large-files-with-git-lfs), [audio files](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-lfs/), ...)

Is there a way to make the file tracked as a large text file (and have the end-of-lines normalized as would be for regular text files) with `git-lfs`?

I am currently using `git-lfs` 1.5.2, and `git` for Windows 2.10.2 (64-bit version) on a Windows 7 platform, with the `core.autocrlf=true` configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some more reading of [git-scm's gitattributes](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion) and some tinkering, I was able to achieve this functionality by defining a custom filter based on `git-lfs`'s own filter (which I found in `~/.gitconfig`) and making use of [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler)'s [unix-to-dos conversion with `sed`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2613834/2994596):

```
[filter "textlfs"]
  clean = sed $'s/$/\\r/' %f | git-lfs clean
  smudge = git-lfs smudge -- %f | sed $'s/\\r$//'
  required = true
```

which can then be used to track large text files on a Windows machine with a `.gitattributes` entry such as:

```
data.txt filter=textlfs diff=textlfs merge=textlfs
```

This however forces the repository users to include this custom filter definition. For convenience you may [include it in a custom `.gitconfig` in your repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18330114/2994596) (note that this requires users to manually include the definition with `git config --local include.path ../.gitconfig`). This should work for users on Windows platforms, but would not be appropriate for users on platforms with different line endings (such as Linux and Mac). A more complex filter could be constructed to handle different platforms using something like:

```
[filter "textlfs"]
  clean = (if [ `uname -s` == "Linux" ]; then cat %f; else sed $'s/$/\\r/' %f; fi) | git-lfs clean
  smudge = git-lfs smudge -- %f | (if [ `uname -s` == "Linux" ]; then cat; else sed $'s/\\r$//'; fi)
  required = true
```

Finally, keep in mind that unless your large text files usually change significantly between updates or they are so big that they exceed file size limits ([such as GitHub's](https://help.github.com/articles/conditions-for-large-files/#100-mb-push-limit)), it may still be advantageous to handle these text files as standard text files (i.e. without `git-lfs`) since [git can efficiently pack text files](https://git-scm.com/book/uz/v2/Git-Internals-Packfiles).