# Git replace protocol only works if it is in .gitconfig which is inside user directory

Tags: git, git-config, .git-folder

I am trying to use the following git replace protocol while running `npm install`,

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

It works well if it is written in the global file (`.gitconfig` inside user directory).

I wanted to move this `.gitconfig` file to the repository folder so that it will be saved in the repository and entire team can use that as described in [Storing git config as part of the repository](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18329621/1822974).  So i have moved it to the repository folder and executed with `include.path` configuration. But it did not work. I tried to add this config inside `.git/config` ( with `--local` flag instead of `--global`) file as well and the result was the same.

It only works when the configuration is written to the global `.gitconfig` file. Is there any restriction for this protocol that it will work only when set globally?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing git config as part of the repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18329621/storing-git-config-as-part-of-the-repository)

Comment: @Dan Lowe, That thread shows how to configure custom config file. The solution given in that thread works for me. If I run `git config --list` , I'm able to see replace configuration. But still npm install is getting failed with message `unknown host GitHub.com`.  But if I move the file to the user directory, npm install works well.