# How can I make sure git config file gets pushed to repo when doing commits?

Tags: git, github, config

I changed git config file on my working machine.

I changed some code, committed it.

When I come home, how can I pull the config file into my home station?

Comment: Whether you should even be committing a config file is questionable, but if you committed this config file you should be able to just do `git pull`.

Answer (score 1):

The git `config` file is inside a repository's `.git` folder. This folder is not part of the repository itself. Thus, changes on the `config` file will not be commited and pushed and subsequently, you won't be able to acquire it via `git pull`.

If you want to have a configuration file that gets shared via your remote repository, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18329621/storing-git-config-as-part-of-the-repository).