# Can I put .gitconfig into a folder so that I can upload it to github?

Tags: git

I want to store my `.gitconfig` on github so that I can quickly set up a new machine by cloning it.

The solution for other config files like `.emacs` or `.spacemacs` is to put them in a folder (`.emacs.d` and `.spacemacs.d` respectively). Is it possible to do the same with `.gitconfig`?

Comment: You could store it in the repository but it won't take effect as soon as one clones the repository. See https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-config#FILES.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing git config as part of the repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18329621/storing-git-config-as-part-of-the-repository)

Answer (score 2):

.gitconfig is always located in your home directory, but you can instead move the file where you want and create a symbolic link to it in your home directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can put `.gitconfig` file to home directory when cloned it from github.

Comment: How to do I put one file (i.e. `.gitconfig`) on github without it being in a folder?

Comment: you should mkdir & git init,then commit,push.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.config/git/config](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-config#FILES) (or set `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` to put it anywhere you like).