# Replicate .git/config file accross all repositories

Tags: git, git-config

I have modified my local .git/config file to allow only fast-forward merges on master branch:

```
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
    mergeOptions = --ff-only
```

However I can't share this file with other repositories by pushing it on the remote server since it is not versioned.

How can I enforce all workstations sharing the same repository to use this option as well?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Storing git config as part of the repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18329621/storing-git-config-as-part-of-the-repository)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there is a way to enforce that.

Although, you could use [Conditional Includes](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_includes) on your home .gitconfig to use specific configurations for specific paths.