# Define commit.template for remote repository

Tags: git, commit, gerrit

I'm trying to define .gitmessage file for repository used by bunch of people.
Can I push this file into origin and somehow save this configuration .git/config:

```
[commit]
  template = <some directory>/.gitmessage
```

as default for everyone who will download repository in future?

Comment: I don't think it's natively supported by Git, but you can always provide a "bootstrap command" that does this sort of setup, and instruct people to use the script via `README` or whatever.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to store a git config as part of the repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18329621/how-to-store-a-git-config-as-part-of-the-repository)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the gerrit [download commands plugin](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/download-commands/+/refs/tags/v3.3.2/src/main/resources/Documentation/config.md#section-gerrit), especially the `gerrit.installCommitExtraCommand`. This allows you to add additional commands to your downloads commands that will be copied to your clipboard.