# .gitattributes UTF-16 to text or JSON by filename without extension

Tags: git, encoding, decoding, utf-16, gitattributes

I have many many files without extensions. I have one file called "model" and another file called "schema" which I know are both UTF-16. Both "model" and "schema" have no extension so are forced to binary when trying to `git diff`. I want to convert "model" to UTF-8 and "schema" to JSON using .gitattributes so I can compare diffs.

**Q1.**
How can I specify individual filenames without extensions to be correctly decoded?

**Q2.** I don't want to add bash scripts or change git --global settings so that its easier to use for others.

I could'nt find any example from [the docs](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes). I tried following [this solution](https://riptutorial.com/git/example/7327/diff-utf-16-encoded-text-and-binary-plist-files) except only using `*model diff=utf16` and git config file:

```
[diff "utf16"]
textconv = "iconv -f utf-16 -t utf-8"
```

but this didn't work. I've tried this in both VScode and on bash (Ubuntu20.04).

**UPDATE:**
@torek pointed me to helpful Git debugging [tool](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables). Here is my output from `GIT_TRACE=1 git diff`

```
09:58:09.927031 git.c:439               trace: built-in: git diff
09:58:09.951640 run-command.c:663       trace: run_command: unset GIT_PAGER_IN_USE; LESS=FRX LV=-c pager
```

**Q1 SOLUTION**
Both @torek and @jthill helped confirm the issue was on my end. The solution above should have worked but my local git config wasn't pointing to the `.gitconfig` file. I updated the `.git/config` file and it worked.

**Q2 SOLUTION**
You must edit global settings once for each repo to reference `.gitconfig`. I've tried following [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18329621/how-to-store-a-git-config-as-part-of-the-repository) but can't seem to get it to revert to the .gitconfig file in the repo worktree root.

Comment: This looks like the right track. `*model` should match, but if you just want the literal file name `model`, write it without the leading `*`. You should be able to run `GIT_TRACE=1 git diff` and see it invoke the text conversion filter, and if so (or even if not), debug from there.

Comment: Thanks @torek. I've added the GIT_TRACE output in the solution but the diff is still to binary files: `Binary files a/model and b/model differ`. How do I know if git diff is picking up the `diff=utf16` textconv arg?

Comment: Based on the trace output, it's not; so now the question is to figure out why not. (If it had, you'd see it run the specified diff filter.)

Comment: For what little it's worth, adding `Makefile diff=foo` to `.gitattributes`, adding `[diff "foo"]` set to `textconv = cat` to `.git/config`, and one line `foo` to the Makefile, and running `GIT_TRACE=1 git diff`, I get: `17:11:46.196341 run-command.c:663       trace: run_command: cat /tmp/SPVsgm_Makefile` just before it shows me the three modified files that aren't `.git/config`. (This is preceded by the same kind of trace you saw, but note the `run_command: cat` part.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> so are forced to binary

By what?

I do:

```
$ echo '/Makefile myattr=test' >.git/info/attributes
$ git ls-files ':(attr:myattr=test)' 
Makefile
$ echo 'Makefile myattr=test' >.git/info/attributes
$ git ls-files ':(attr:myattr=test)' | wc -l
24
```

so there's 24 Makefiles and the anchored pattern matches only the specific one I want, because I anchored the path.

So put `/model diff=utf16` in your `.gitattributes` if that file's at the work tree root.

Comment: Thanks @jthill. This confirms something is wrong on my end and also shown by toreks comments above.