# Git Ignore Case-Sensitive Folder Names

Tags: windows, git, gitignore, case-sensitive, git-config

There's lots of questions/answers on [committing filename changes on case-insensitive OS's](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17683458/6069586), but my problem is git-ignoring a case sensitive folder (on both linux and windows).

Example: key 3rd-party software tool generates folder `Test/` with build artifacts for testing.
Standard location for test files in our system are `test/` folders.
The gitignore has `**/Test/` (what we don't want to see/commit), but then `test/` folders don't show up (what we do want to see/commit).

Testing this on latest windows git-bash, setting/toggling `core.ignorecase = false` doesn't seem to change the behavior.

Edit: From VonC's useful command to check per-file gitignore status, a demo

```
git init
mkdir -p d1/Test d2/test
touch d1/Test/hidden d2/test/visible
git config -f .gitconfig --add core.ignorecase false
echo "**/Test/" > .gitignore
```

`git status`

```
Untracked files:
.gitconfig
.gitignore
# Missing d2/test/visible
```

`git -c core.ignorecase=false check-ignore -v  --  d1/Test/hidden`

```
.gitignore:1:**/Test/    d1/Test/hidden
```

`git -c core.ignorecase=false check-ignore -v  --  d2/test/visible`

```
# Nothing, which is correct
```

Second Edit:

Which leads to the (less) obvious problem: [forgetting to add .gitconfig to local config](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18330114/6069586): (of course it won't behave like it's changed if it's not actually changed...)

`git config --local include.path ../.gitconfig`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> setting/toggling core.ignorecase = false doesn't seem to change the behavior.

It should though.

Test it out with a file within that folder:

```
git -c core.ignorecase=false check-ignore -v  --  Test/a/File
```

Another approach would be to sidestep the issue entirely and make sure:

- the standard location is, for instance, in `tests/` instead of `test/`,
- or the key software generates tests in `Tests/` instead of `Test/`.