# git: store config options permanent with repository

Tags: git

How one can made config options like

[gc]
reflogExpire = never

be permanent with the repository, so they get pushed / pulled and cloned (everybody using the repository get em automatically)

Comment: Related but not duplicate: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42785/can-git-configuration-be-set-across-multiple-repositories  I suspect it cannot be done directly, as the config never gets pushed or pulled as far as I know.

Comment: My approach with something like this is to include a script in the repo that the readme says you should run whenever you clone the repo. Then it's trivial for each developer to apply on their machine. But it's flaky: so far, my "please, every one, run this script" efforts have only yielded relatively low compliance rates. They typically get run by any given developer only when they hit the problem that script tried to prevent in the first place...

Comment: Ah, this one is a duplicate of your question, with a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18329621/how-to-store-a-git-config-as-part-of-the-repository

Comment: @joanis OK that's exactly my solution I am currently trying. But as you stated, I do not a high adoption rate...

Comment: Git intentionally doesn't let you store config in the repository because anyone who can make changes to the repo config can execute arbitrary code.  A standardized setup script is your best bet here, but that depends on your users trusting you enough to run it.

Comment: This is why I like git more every day: clever design (code execution possible by config files...), usefull defaults like autoclf and reflog expire + the possibility to change that defaults at least on project level.... jesus help.