# Set up sparse-checkout at the repo level (vs. local config)

Tags: git, git-submodules, sparse-checkout

I have a situation where I have some submodules that I want to do partial checkouts of. I was able to get this working with `git sparse-checkout`, by manually editing `.git/info/modules/NAME/info/sparse-checkout`. However, I want this setting to be saved in the repository itself, so that anyone who uses the repository only checks out that one directory in the submodule. Is there a way to store this in some sort of repository-level config vs. the local-level one?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18329621/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+store+config+in+the+repository For your next question "How to do this simple and automatic for everyone who clones my repo?" the answer is "Sorry, no way".