# Hide untracked and other files from terminal in git

Tags: git, git-bash, git-status

we set up a git for magento site.

and we edited lot of files and now when I used command : `git status`

I can see as in below images. I want to hide these files from terminal, but I dint want to delete it.

Is there any way I can hide from terminal.

[image]

[image]

Comment: no , i dont want to see these files in terminal

Comment: but if i dit these files again, i want to see under modified files list.

Comment: `git add <modified files> / git rm <deleted files> + git commit` ?

Comment: i added succesfully, but when i tried to remove i am getting this http://prntscr.com/a831x4  because that folder is not exists in server

Comment: @LeGEC i created that folder in server, but still getting same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you want to do ?

If you want to view the modifications in a specific subfolder :

```
git status business/logic/
```

If you want to hide the lines regarding `app/code` :

```
git status | grep -v "app/code"
```

Answer (score 7):

use this

```
git status -uno
```

which is equivalent to:

```
git status --untracked-files=no
```

It's a bit hidden in the manuals, but the manpage for status says "supports the same options as git-commit", so that's where you'd have to look.

Comment: if i run this command `git status -uno` , i can hide files in image 2, but i want to hide files in image 1 also.

Comment: have you added `.gitignor` file ?

Comment: i didt added that file, is i need to add that file in server ?

Comment: you have to add in your git repo.
 check the last answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774416/get-git-not-to-show-untracked-files.

Comment: A .gitignore file will only ignore files that are not in the repository yet. That won't fix the tracked files shown as modified.

Comment: @DeveloperDemetri i want to hide modified files as well.

Comment: @BabyinCoding modified files are not untracked files. like `.php` files.

Comment: you can add `*.php` in `.gitignore` file.
then files with `.php` will not be shown in `git status`.

Comment: @UsmanMaqbool .gitignore only ignores files that have **never** been committed yet. That won't do anything for the files that show up as modified already.

Answer (score 2):

@Usman Maqbool's answer will work for files that have never been committed yet, and are considered 'untracked' by Git. For files that have already been added to the repo, but you want to ignore local changes, you have 2 options, as discussed [here](http://blog.crushingboredom.com/git-the-lesser-known-skip-worktree/).

I would recommend using the `git update-index --skip-worktree [filename]` option, as that appears safer.

Comment: after running this command `git update-index --skip-worktree' if i edit the same files again, will it come under "modified files" list ?

Comment: @BabyinCoding did not mentioned about committed files. He just mentioned `git status`.

Comment: I honestly haven't used this myself, but from the command description it looks like Git will ignore any local changes until you go back and run ' 
git update-index --no-skip-worktree [filename]' on those files. The link that I posted explains more: http://blog.crushingboredom.com/git-the-lesser-known-skip-worktree/

Comment: @UsmanMaqbool I am talking about files that have been committed at some point in time by someone, hence they are in the online repo and tracked by Git. Using a .gitignore will do nothing to these files. A .gitignore only tells Git to start ignoring any _new_ files that match the given regex. Please feel free to read more at https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363197/can-i-get-a-list-of-files-marked-assume-unchanged seems best solution for it.

Comment: @UsmanMaqbool the link I posted includes the --assume-unchanged and discusses why --skip-worktree is a safer option. Besides, the link you just posted isn't a guide to marking them unchanged, it's a solution for checking which files are marked unchanged.