# How to ignore some special file in gitignore?

Tags: git

I want to ignore some special file in .gitignore. E.g. symTbl.c, there will be some this kind of files generated by compiler and they are in different sub-directories.
Meanwhile I need to accept all the other .c files.

So my .gitignore will be like below:

```
*
!*/
!*.c
symTbl.c
```

But still the symTbl.c cannot be ignored.
How to do then? Thanks!

**Note**:
I have some other files which should not be tracked, e.g. .lzs .bin... So I need to ignore * first and then  use !*.c to track *.c. By doing so, I cannot simply put symTbl.c in .gitignore.

Comment: Are you sure you can't just ignore the files that need to be ignored, rather than trying to ignore everything but .c? If there are too many or they don't follow nice patterns, you could also consider [ignoring untracked files by default](http://stackoverflow.com/a/600815/344821).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put just

```
symTbl.c
```

in your `.gitignore` file in the root of your project. Files already tracked cannot be ignored. Check with `git ls-files | grep symTbl.c` if you have already commited one and delete it (`git ls-files | grep symTbl.c | xargs -d'\n' rm` to delete them directly)

EDIT

I've done a new repo and put these files in it

```
# show all files, excluding those in the .git directory
$ tree -a -I .git
.
├── bla.bin
├── bla.c
├── foo
│   ├── bla.bin
│   ├── bla.c
│   └── symTbl.c
├── .gitignore
└── symTbl.c

1 directory, 7 files
```

My .gitignore contains what you had:

```
$ cat .gitignore
*
!*/
!*.c
symTbl.c
```

And running `git add .` just added the different `bla.c` files in the root and in the `foo/` directory:

```
$ git add .
$ git status
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   new file:   bla.c
#   new file:   foo/bla.c
#
```

So probably you have already committed your `symTbl.c` files? If so, `git rm` them and they will be properly ignored from now on.

Comment: Please check my main post for further explanation of my situation, thank you for your help!

Comment: If the files are already tracked, they cannot be ignored. Are you sure this is not the problem you are having? Try `git rm -r --cached .` then `git add -A`. See if the files are now untracked.

Comment: Thank you very much! Also thank @AdamKDean! You are right. The key should be `git rm` or `git rm -r --cached .`